# Solve $T(n) = 3T(n/4) + n$ with iteration technique only

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Solve $T(n) = 3T(n/4) + n$ with iteration technique only

I've got a solution for this one, but I did not understand what is pointed in red there, can anyone please explain how they did it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$a^{\log_c(b)}=e^{\log(a)\log_c(b)}=e^{\log(a)\log(b)/\log(c)}=b^{\log_c(a)}$$

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes sense. I didn't know that :(

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS, you are welcome.